# C# Socket Networking

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

I've been trying the Sockets library and the code is probably messy so, sorry for that. The problem is that after sending some message there is a significant delay between the when the message was sent and then the message is received on the other end. My question is why? Also I want to add some kind of authentication for the connection you can also help me with that.

Here is the code for the Client and Server class.

Server:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Networking_Experimenting
{
    internal class CustomServer
    {
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private Socket listener;
        private Socket currentConnection;
        //Currently not used
        private string password = "E36";

        public CustomServer(string host, int port)
        {
            Server(host, port).Wait();
        }

        public async Task Server(string host, int port)
        {
            await ServerInit(host, port);
            await ListenForConnection();
        }

        public async Task ServerInit(string host, int port)
        {
            ipEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Parse(host), port);
            listener = new(
                ipEndPoint.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
            listener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
        }

        private async Task ListenForConnection()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            try
            {
                listener.Listen(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Server started listening for connections.");

                // Set up a task to wait for a connection
                Task<Socket> acceptTask = listener.AcceptAsync();

                // Set up a delay task for 1 minute
                Task delayTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

                // Wait for either a connection or the timeout
                Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(acceptTask, delayTask);

                if (completedTask == acceptTask)
                {
                    // Connection received
                    currentConnection = await acceptTask;
                    Console.WriteLine("Connection received.");

                    //Add authentication logic

                    while (true)
                    {
                        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                var buffer = new byte[1024];
                                var receiveSize = await currentConnection.ReceiveAsync(
                                buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                                var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                                buffer, 0, receiveSize);
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedMessage))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Client: " + receivedMessage);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                string message = Console.ReadLine();
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                                {
                                    byte[] encodedMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                                    await currentConnection.SendAsync(encodedMsg, SocketFlags.None);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                // Timeout occurred
                Console.WriteLine("Server timed out waiting for connection.");
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down the server.");
                listener.Dispose();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server timed out waiting for connection.");
                Console.WriteLine("Shutting down the server.");
            }
            finally
            {
                listener.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace Networking_Experimenting
{
    internal class CustomClient
    {
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint;
        private Socket client;
        private string connectionID = "E36";

        public CustomClient()
        {
            Client().Wait();
        }

        public async Task Client()
        {
            await ClientInit();
            await StartClient();
        }

        public async Task ClientInit()
        {
            ipEndPoint = new(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            client = new(
                ipEndPoint.AddressFamily,
                SocketType.Stream,
                ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        private async Task StartClient()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the Server IP and port separated by a / be CAREFUL!");
            string[] IPPort;

            while (true)
            {
                IPPort = Console.ReadLine().Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (IPPort.Length < 2 || IPPort.Length > 2)
                    Console.WriteLine("You entered the IP and port wrong! Try again.");

                else
                    break;
            }

            IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Parse(IPPort[0]);
            int serverport = int.Parse(IPPort[1]);
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, serverport);

            await client.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint);

            //Currently only for demonstration
            string authMessage = connectionID;
            byte[] authBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authMessage);
            await client.SendAsync(authBytes, SocketFlags.None);
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication message sent.");

            //Add authentication logic

            Console.WriteLine("Authentication successful. Connection accepted.");
            Console.WriteLine("For example, say Hi!");

            while (true)
            {
                // Start listening for incoming messages from the server
                _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[1024];
                        var receiveSize = await client.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);
                        var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveSize);
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedMessage))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Server: " + receivedMessage);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Continuously send messages to the server
                _ = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string message = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                        {
                            byte[] encodedMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                            await client.SendAsync(encodedMsg, SocketFlags.None); // Await here
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Socket programming is *hard*. Like "multiple books" hard. I strongly suggest you use a pre-rolled library such as gRPC. Can you do it yourself? Sure. But it'll probably be a nightmare of security, threading, allocation, etc problems.

Comment: Thanks you! But I'm doing this because there is a local programming competition in a few months and one feature that you need to implement is multiplayer it's not a complex game but I don't want to do it like I did it the previous time 2 people on 1 machine. My idea with the socket library it to use it to host local games and use it to transfer the necessary data for the game to be played on 2 separate machines on the same network. I'm doing it from scratch because I haven't looked into what libraries are there and the impress factor will be greater if it's from scratch.

Comment: the line `var receiveSize = await currentConnection.ReceiveAsync(buffer, SocketFlags.None);` and `var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveSize);` suggests to me that *this task is beyond your aims/timescale*; that is not valid - you'd need to understand stream-vs-message networking, framing, buffering, etc; you *might* want to look at `Socket.NoDelay`, but: there are much bigger problems here

Comment: Do you mind telling me what the other problems are?

Comment: Also async, disposal, and that outer `while (true)` all come to mind at a quick glance. There are so many things wrong here it's hard to know where to start.